# Bounds on volume of a Riemannian manifold given its diameter

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, volume

Suppose that we are given an $n$-dimensional Riemmanian manifold $M$. Then it is naturally endowed with a metric function $d$ compatible with Riemannian structure (the distance of two points is the infimum of lengths of all curves connecting the two points). Suppose that the diameter of the manifold is finite, i.e.
$$ L = \mathrm{sup}_{x,y \in M} d(x,y) < \infty. $$
The question is what can be said about the volume of the manifold. In particular, is it true that there exist constants $c,C >0$ such that
$$ c L^d \leq vol(M) \leq C L^d. $$
If this helps I am happy with results with additional assumptions, e.g. that $M$ is compact.

Comment: What is $d$ in $L^d$? Or did you mean "there exist constants $c,C,d$" ?  And how is volume defined?

Comment: @lisyarus Presumably $d := \dim M$. Provided $M$ is oriented, $g$ determines a natural oriented volume form $\textrm{vol}$, and the volume is, by definition $\int_M \textrm{vol}$.

Comment: @Travis Dimension was defined earlier as $n$, that's why I asked. Considering the volume, the orientation is what confuses me. Is it really necessary for the non-signed volume (that is, a measure, not an $n$-form) to be defined?

Comment: One can dispense with the orientation condition here at the cost of replacing the $n$-form $\textrm{vol}$ with a "volume density", which behaves something like an $n$-form determined up to sign, whose definition is a little more sophisticated.

Comment: I meant $n$ instead of $d$ but it is also interesting to ask more general question: is this true for some $d$. Of course all the constants may depend on the dimension, but not on the manifold $M$ itself. Other types of bounds are also interesting. As for the question about the definition of volume, you can always construct the so called volume pseudoform and its integral is positive. It works also for nonorientable manifolds. I think it is intuitively clear that the area of a Mobius strip is well defined.

Comment: @Blazej Okay, just asked for clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the surface of a cylinder of length $L$ and diameter $D$ the surface is $\pi D L$ and since $D$ can be arbitrarily small there is no lower bound of the form you state.

For a piece of hyperbolic surface the volume grows exponentially with the diameter. So there is not such an upper bound either. See e.g. [Hyperbolic Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry)

Comment: It seemsa that in your cylinder example you treat *diameter* as doubled radius, not the supremum of distances between points. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think of cylinder as embedded in 3-space. Diameter and length refer to the embedded cylinder. The diameter of the surface (as a Riemannian manifold) is of order $L$ when $D$ goes to zero.

Comment: Your answer clearly shows that lower bound doesn't exist and that upper bound of the type I mentoned also doesn't. Do you know something about more general question: Is it possible to constuct a (finite and positive) function $f$ such that $vol(M) \leq f(L)$? For example, $vol(M) \leq A \exp ( B L^C )$ for some constants $A,B,C$.

Comment: That's actually a good question. As far as I recall, for hyperbolic surfaces there are bounds involving the curvature. When curvature increases, the bounds go to infinity (so your constant $B$ may not be uniformly bounded). There is, however, some relationship between volume, surface and radii (of balls) which possibly could produce bounds in the direction you ask for? But I wouldn't know how to write down a general inequality.

Comment: I will probably accept your answer later because strictly speaking it settles the issue that I raised in the original question, but I want to still keep the thread open for a while - maybe someone will be able to write something about more general problem.

Comment: I think I can imagine a sequence of manifolds of fixed diameter and volume increasing without bound. I'm thinking of two spheres that are connected by $n$ cylindrical "tunnels." Adding a tunnel increases the volume but does not change the diameter. This shows that no upper bound exists. But as @H. H. Rugh mentioned, given a bound on the curvature, there may be something that could be said.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that it's been a while since this question has been posted, this answer probably won't be very useful.

The answer given above is of the form: "There is a smooth manifold M such that one can pick a Riemannian metric for which the diameter equals $1$ while the volume can be arbitrarily small." There is in fact a stronger statement one can make, that is, for any smooth and compact manifold M with dimension at least 2, there are metrics with constant diameter whose volume can be made arbitrarily small. The proof is as follows.

Take a surjective smooth map $f: M \rightarrow [0,1]$. The interval is equipped with its standard metric. One can pull it back by $f$ to obtain a rank at most 1 semi-definite inner product $g_0$. Take any metric $g$ on $M$. The metric $ g_0 + \epsilon g$ will have diameter at least $1$, since any curve connecting $f^{-1}(0)$ with $f^{-1} (1) $ will have length at least $1$. Moreover, picking $\epsilon$ accordingly, one can make the natural volume form of $ g_0 + \epsilon g$ arbitrarily small. Neat, right?